# Bitmap caching doesn't work

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I'm trying to cache my downloaded bitmaps using google code but it's not working for me.

I download the code from this article: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

And used it in my code, I couldn't find any good example for using so I guess I may not using it correctly.

In my OnCreate I have this line:

```
init(new ImageCacheParams(this, this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getPath()));
```

The init methods:

```
  private void init(ImageCacheParams cacheParams) {
                        mCacheParams = cacheParams;

                        // Set up memory cache
                        if (mCacheParams.memoryCacheEnabled) {
                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Memory cache created (size = " + mCacheParams.memCacheSize + ")");
                            }

                            // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then
                            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                                mReusableBitmaps = new HashSet<SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
                            }

                            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, BitmapDrawable>(mCacheParams.memCacheSize) {

                                /**
                                 * Notify the removed entry that is no longer being cached
                                 */
                                @Override
                                protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key,
                                        BitmapDrawable oldValue, BitmapDrawable newValue) {
                                    if (RecyclingBitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(oldValue)) {
                                        // The removed entry is a recycling drawable, so notify it 
                                        // that it has been removed from the memory cache
                                        ((RecyclingBitmapDrawable) oldValue).setIsCached(false);
                                    } else {
                                        // The removed entry is a standard BitmapDrawable

                                        if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                                            // We're running on Honeycomb or later, so add the bitmap
                                            // to a SoftRefrence set for possible use with inBitmap later
                                            mReusableBitmaps.add(new SoftReference<Bitmap>(oldValue.getBitmap()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                /**
                                 * Measure item size in kilobytes rather than units which is more practical
                                 * for a bitmap cache
                                 */
                                @Override
                                protected int sizeOf(String key, BitmapDrawable value) {
                                    final int bitmapSize = getBitmapSize(value) / 1024;
                                    return bitmapSize == 0 ? 1 : bitmapSize;
                                }
                            };
                        }

                        // By default the disk cache is not initialized here as it should be initialized
                        // on a separate thread due to disk access.
                        if (cacheParams.initDiskCacheOnCreate) {
                            // Set up disk cache
                           new InitializesCache().execute();
                        }
                    }

 class InitializesCache extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
                {

                    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
                         initDiskCache();
                        return null;
                    }


public void initDiskCache() {
                    // Set up disk cache
                    synchronized (mDiskCacheLock) {
                        if (mDiskLruCache == null || mDiskLruCache.isClosed()) {
                            File diskCacheDir = mCacheParams.diskCacheDir;
                            if (mCacheParams.diskCacheEnabled && diskCacheDir != null) {
                                if (!diskCacheDir.exists()) {
                                    diskCacheDir.mkdirs();
                                }
                                if (getUsableSpace(diskCacheDir) > mCacheParams.diskCacheSize) {
                                    try {
                                        mDiskLruCache = DiskLruCache.open(
                                                diskCacheDir, 1, 1, mCacheParams.diskCacheSize);
                                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Disk cache initialized");
                                        }
                                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                                        mCacheParams.diskCacheDir = null;
                                        Log.e(TAG, "initDiskCache - " + e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mDiskCacheStarting = false;
                        mDiskCacheLock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
```

Now I use this line when I download my bitmap from my own db:

```
addBitmapToCache("foo", *some drawable*);
```

The method:

```
public void addBitmapToCache(String data, BitmapDrawable value) {
                    if (data == null || value == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Add to memory cache
                    if (mMemoryCache != null) {
                        if (RecyclingBitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(value)) {
                            // The removed entry is a recycling drawable, so notify it 
                            // that it has been added into the memory cache
                            ((RecyclingBitmapDrawable) value).setIsCached(true);
                        }
                        mMemoryCache.put(data, value);
                    }

                    synchronized (mDiskCacheLock) {
                        // Add to disk cache
                        if (mDiskLruCache != null) {
                            final String key = hashKeyForDisk(data);
                            OutputStream out = null;
                            try {
                                DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = mDiskLruCache.get(key);
                                if (snapshot == null) {
                                    final DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mDiskLruCache.edit(key);
                                    if (editor != null) {
                                        out = editor.newOutputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX);
                                        value.getBitmap().compress(
                                                mCacheParams.compressFormat, mCacheParams.compressQuality, out);
                                        editor.commit();
                                        out.close();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    snapshot.getInputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX).close();
                                }
                            } catch (final IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "addBitmapToCache - " + e);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "addBitmapToCache - " + e);
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (out != null) {
                                        out.close();
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

After that I try to get the bitmap by calling this:

```
tempImage.setImageDrawable(getBitmapFromMemCache("foo"));

 public BitmapDrawable getBitmapFromMemCache(String data) {
                    BitmapDrawable memValue = null;

                    if (mMemoryCache != null) {
                        memValue = mMemoryCache.get(data);
                    }

                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && memValue != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Memory cache hit");
                    }

                    return memValue;
                }
```

When using this flow I don't see my bitmap I also don't get any errors.

I also tried to look at other git codes for doing cache but all the codes are really not clear how to use, with lack of example or none description at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [library Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading and caching bitmaps